# Spring Boot Data REST @JsonValue POJO serializes as POJO with content field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-rest

I am using spring boot 1.5.1.RELEASE, with jackson as MessageConverter.

One of my POJO is looking something like following:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Pojo1 {
  @Id
  private final String id;
  private final NestedValue payload;
}

public class NestedValue {
  private final String value;

  public NestedValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static NestedValue(String value) {
    return new NestedValue(value);
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = 'pojos', path='pojos')
public interface Pojo1Repository extends MongoRepository<Pojo, String> {
}
```

I am expecting above to be serialized as this:

```
{
  "payload": "value projected by getValue()"
}
```

Instead, I am getting as below:

```
{
  "payload": {
      "content": "value projected by getValue()"
  }
}
```

If I test it with default `ObjectMapper`, POJO is serialized as I expected.
Is there a hidden jackson feature that is configured by Spring???

Comment: Are you sure your pojos are these? you said they are something like these. Can you share the exact pojo classes?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When I add `@Getter` and `@AllArgsConstructor` to `NestedValue` to make it compile and then use a Spring `@RestController` to return a `Pojo1`, the serialization works as expected. Please share your actual code.

Comment: What kind of MessageConverter do you use?

Comment: @Sergii I am using default spring `MappingJackson2MessageConverte` configured automatically via spring-boot

Comment: @shi My POJO looks very similar to above.

Comment: @hzpz I am using Spring Data REST (projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest) with MongoRepository

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. When I create an ObjectMapper and serialize the pojo "manually" the @JsonValue annotated field is used: 

    "playerGroups":[1,2,3,4,5,6],

But when the request goes through spring data rest renders the respons it shows like this:

     "playerGroups": [
                {
                  "content": 0
                },
                {
                  "content": 1
                },
                {
                  "content": 2
                },